# Is a heapsort/Priority queue better than a map (ordered map in STL) in C++ in terms of time complexity?

Tags: c++, time, heap, priority-queue, stdmap

This is a question that has been bugging for me a long time.

I have a huge dataset and I want to sort that dataset using a number that is generated each time a for loop is run throughout that dataset. So, I decided to bind that number to the index of a row in a map. This way, I have indirectly sorted the the dataset (which is a 2D vector of strings). Now I have been told there is a better way for me to do this, preferably by the heap data structure. But I do not know how a heap, like a priority queue would be helpful in this situation (except for being able to print out the smallest element in the heap which would take O(n) time). And I am strictly talking about time complexity here. I'll show you the code that I have:

```
`  for(i = 0; i < final_dataset.size(); i+=2){
  string str1 = final_dataset[i][0];   
  string str2 = final_dataset[i][3];  
  string str3 = final_dataset[i+1][3]; 

  istringstream(str2) >> num2;        
  istringstream(str3) >> num3;        

  total_date_diff = date_calc(str1, numeric_year, numeric_month);    //Calculate the difference in input date and the dates in the final_dataset
  num2 = d2 - num2;                                                 //Calculate the difference in supplies
  num3 = d3 - num3;                                                 //Calculate the difference in exports
  euclid_result = euclid_distance_result(total_date_diff,num2, num3);   //Calculate the euclidian distance for every row in the final_dataset

  results.insert(pair<double, int>(euclid_result, i));        //Bind the respective euclidian distances to the row index of every row in the final_dataset
  
}


int k_counter = 0;   

cout<<"The "<<k<<" nearest neighbors of entered data point are: \n\n";

//iterate through the map, results(key:euclidian distance, value: corresponding row index) to output the datapoints, in terms of increasing order of euclidian distances.
//Since maps are sorted automatically in ascending order, display the datapoints(taken from the rows of the final_dataset) corresponding to the first k values in the map.
for(auto itr = results.begin(); itr != results.end(); itr++){


  cout<<"("<<final_dataset[itr->second][0]<<","<<final_dataset[itr->second][3]<<","
  <<final_dataset[itr->second+1][3]<<")"<<" with the label: "
  <<final_dataset[itr->second][1]<<"\t"<<" and Euclidian distance="<<itr->first<<"\n";
  k_counter++;
  if(k_counter == k) break;   //once k is reached, stop iterating
}
```

How could a priority queue possible make it faster than what I did?

Comment: There are reasons why different containers exist. They have different properties, and different use cases. Comparing only the "time complexity" of each is like trying to make a meaningful comparison between apples and onions. One is not a complete substitute for the other, with the only difference being "time complexity".

Comment: Okay, um, what if keeping my job depends on answering this question?

Comment: Map is a node based data structure (such as a red-black tree), so inserting all your elements one at a time is quite expensive both in compute and memory.  It's better to copy your elements to another vector and then do a `std::sort`.  (Or `std::make_heap` + `std::sort_heap` if you're really hung up on heaps for some reason.)  Both methods can will work directly on the original data as well if it's OK to mutate it.  As to your second question, let's hope the boss doesn't read Stack Overflow.

Comment: The answer to the question does not depend on someone's job.

Comment: @Freexanman You will hopefully have a few internships beyond this one. All a part of being an undergrad, albeit it's quite weird you got one before even going through the basics such as data structure class which should have made it clear how to compare data structures and pick one that gets the job done.

Comment: If you really care about time complexity only, then you can simply use a linear time (O(n)) sorting algorithm (there are many in the literature). However all such algorithms have a big tradeoff - they use a lot of extra space. So much that they may not be practical at all for your data set. Of course, only you can determine whether that's the case - we don't know what your dataset is.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on C++ [maps](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) says:

> Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees.

This implies that insertion of one key/value pair has a time complexity of O(log), where  is the size of the map at the time of insertion.

To insert all key/value pairs you will thus have a total time complexity of O(log1 + log2 + log3 + ... + log) = O(log(!)) = O(log)

This is the same time complexity you get from storing the key/value pairs in a vector and sorting it by key calling [`std::sort`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

### Heap

A heap-based algorithm can have an advantage when you don't really need to sort the *whole* input, but are only interested in the least  elements, or maybe even only the least <sup>th</sup> element.

Inserting into a heap has also a time complexity of O(log), where  is the size of the heap at the time of insertion.

However, a well designed heap-based algorithm will not need the heap to have more than  elements: once that size is reached, values are *exchanged* -- also with O(log) time complexity. So the overall time complexity will then be O(log). This is definitely an improvement on O(log) when  ≪ .

Comment: "This is the same time complexity" Same complexity, yes. And yet an `std::sort` of an `std::vector<std::pair<K,V>>` with small K and V beats building a `std::map<K,V>` from scratch typically by leaps and bounds, as sorting a vector all at once yields a 10-100x lower real world cost due to significantly better data locality in a well chosen sorting algorithm compared to tree traversal.

Comment: @Ext3h, true. *"with small K and V beats..."*: this is a practical consideration when designing an algorithm when you know the upper bounds to deal with. Time complexity is about asymptotic behaviour for increasingly large input parameters. And the Asker's question was specifically about *"better...in terms of time complexity"*

Comment: @Freexanman, could you leave some feed-back? Did this answer your question?